# First Neural Network, (MLP), from Scratch, Python -- Questions

Tags: python, neural-network, digits

I understand how the Neural Network with backpropogation is supposed to work.  I know how to use Python's own *MLPClassifier* and *fit* functions work in sklearn.  I am creating my own because I'd like to know the details better.  I will first show my code (with comments) and then discuss my problems.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sklearn as ML

# z: the linear combination of the previous layer
#
# returns the activation for the node
#
def sigmoid(z):

    a = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

    return a

# z: the contribution of a layer
#
# returns the derivative of the sigmoid evaluated at z   
# 
def sig_grad(z):

    d = (1 - sigmoid(z))*sigmoid(z)

    return d

# input: the data we want to train the network with
# hidden_layers: the number of nodes in the hidden layers
# num_layers: how many hidden layers between the input layer and the output     layer
# num_output: how many outputs there are... this becomes relevant when we     input many features.
#
# returns the activations determined
#         and the linear combinations of previous layer's nodes for each     layer
#
def feedforward(input, hidden_layers, num_layers, num_output, thresh,     weights):

#initialize the vector for inputs AND threshold values
X = np.hstack([thresh[0], input])
#intialize the activations list
A = []
#intialize the linear combos for each layer
Z = []
w = list(weights)

#place ones in the first row of each layer of weights for the threshold
w[0] = np.vstack([np.ones([1,hidden_layers]), w[0]])

for i in range(1,num_layers): 
        w[i] = np.vstack([np.ones([1,hidden_layers]), weights[i]])

w[-1] = np.vstack([np.ones([1,num_output]), w[-1]])

#the first layer of weights are initialized outside function
#cycle through the hidden layers
for i in range(1, num_layers+1):

    Z.append( np.dot(X, w[i-1])); S = sigmoid(Z[i-1]); A.append(S); X = np.hstack([thresh[i], A[i-1]])

#find the output/last layer activations
Z.append( np.dot(X, w[-1]) ); S = sigmoid(Z[-1]); A.append(S);

return A, Z

#
# truth: what we know the output should be
# activations: the activations determined at each node by the sigmoid 
#               function in the previous feedforward pass
# combos: the linear combinations at each layer in the prev. ff pass
# num_layers: the number of hidden layers
#
# error: the errors determined at each layer; will be needed for gradient     descent
#
def backprop(input, truth, activations, combos, num_layers, weights):

    #initialize an array of errors for each hidden layer and the output layer
    error = [0 for x in range(0,num_layers+1)]
    #intialize the lists containing the gradients w.r.t. weights and threshold
    derivW = []; derivb = []

    #set the output layer since its error is computed differently than the others
    error[num_layers] = (activations[num_layers] - truth)*sig_grad(combos[num_layers])
    #find the rate of change for weights and thresh for connections to output
    derivW.append( activations[num_layers-1]*error[num_layers]); derivb.append(np.sum(error[num_layers]))

    if(num_layers > 1):
    #find the errors for each of the hidden layers
    for i in range(num_layers - 1, 0, -1):
        error[i] =  np.dot(weights[i+1],error[i+1])*sig_grad(combos[i])
        derivW.append( np.outer(activations[i-1], error[i]) ); derivb.append(np.sum(error[i]))

    #    
    #finding the derivative for weights of input to next layer
    #    
    error[0] = np.dot(weights[i],error[i])*sig_grad(combos[0])        
    derivW.append( np.outer(input, error[0]) ); derivb.append(np.sum(error[0]))

    return derivW, derivb   

#
# weights: our networks weights to update via gradient descent
# thresh: the threshold values to update for our system
# derivb: the derivative of our cost function with respect to b for each  layer
# derivW: the derivative of our cost function with respect to W for each layer
# stepsize: the stepsize we want to take, determines how big of a step we take
#
# returns the updated weights and threshold values for our network
def gradDesc(weights, thresh, derivb, derivW, stepsize, num_layers):

    #perform gradient descent
    for j in range(100):
        for i in range(0, num_layers + 1):

            weights[i] = weights[i] - stepsize*derivW[num_layers-i]
            thresh[i] = thresh[i] - stepsize*derivb[num_layers-i]


    return weights, thresh


#input: the data to send through the network
#hidden_layers: the number of hidden_layers between the input layer and the output layer
#num_layers: the number of nodes in the hidden layer
#num_output: the number of nodes in the output layer
#
#returns the output of the network
#
def nNetwork(input, truth, hidden_layers, num_layers, num_output, maxiter, stepsize):

    #assuming that input is an array where each element is an input/sample
    #we also need to know the size of each sample itself
    m = input.size

    thresh = np.random.randn(num_layers + 1, 1)
    thresh_weights = np.ones([num_layers + 1, 1])

    # initialize the weights as a list because each layer might have
    # a different number of weights
    weights = []; weights.append(np.random.randn(m,hidden_layers)); 

    if( num_layers > 1):
        for i in range(1, num_layers):

            weights.append(np.random.randn(hidden_layers, hidden_layers))

    weights.append(np.random.randn(hidden_layers, num_output)) 

    for i in range(maxiter):

        activations, combos = feedforward(input, hidden_layers, num_layers, num_output, thresh, weights)

        derivW, derivb = backprop(input, truth, activations, combos, num_layers, weights)

        weights, thresh = gradDesc(weights, thresh, derivb, derivW, stepsize, num_layers)

    return weights, thresh

def main():

    # a very, very simple neural network
    input = np.array([1,0,0])
    truth = 0
    hidden_layers = 3
    num_layers = 2
    num_output = 1

    #train the network
    w, t = nNetwork(input, truth, hidden_layers, num_layers, num_output, maxiter = 10, stepsize = 0.001)

    #test the network on a new set of arguments
    #activations, combos = feedforward(new_input, hidden_layers = 3, num_layers = 2, thresh = t, weights = w)

main()
```

I've tested this code on simple examples where there are n input of one dimension and output of n dimension (not yet able to work out the bugs when I type import NN.py into the console, but works when I run it piece by piece in the console).  I have a few questions to help me better understand what is going on when I have n input there are m dimensions. For example, the digits data in Python (there are 1797 samples and each sample is 64x1 -- an 8x8 image vectorized).

1) Is each of the 64 pixels considered an input?  If so, is the neural net trained one image at a time?  This would be an easy fix for me.

2) If the neural net is trained all images at once, what are suggestions for modifying my code?

3) Obviously the output for an image comes in the form of 0, 1, 2, 3, ... , or 9.  But, does the output come in the form of a vector 10x1 where there is a 1 in the digit the image represents and 0's elsewhere?  So, my prediction vector would have the highest value where the 1 might be, right?

4) Then, I'm not quite sure how #3 would look if #2 is true..

I apologize for the long note.  Thanks for taking a look and helping me understand better!

Comment: It is much harder to understand your questions than the code. Looking at the code the answers would be more or less 1) is false; 2) follows from (1) ; 3) is true ; 4) online and batch learning modes can use the same output encoding. Try to understand the theory, then the code and only afterwards get back to your questions.

Comment: I guess I wasn't sure what form the output takes.  Your answers help.  Thank you @DmitriChubarov.